# Large Training Set For NER

Tags: spacy

I have a project that involves taking property descriptions and labeling key data elements. I decided to use spaCy in an effort to train my own NER pipe since these descriptions are not written like conventional sentences. However, when I go to train it gets to about 20% and then crashes and i am unable to find an explanation.

**How it's set up**

Below is a sample of my JSON. The full JSON is 2.6 MB and contains >1000 descriptions ranging from 40 - ~500 tokens. The file contains ~54000 tokens in total. (Be advised the below data has been changed to not reflect the actual property)

```
[{
    "id": 1, "paragraphs": 
    [{
    "raw": "Lots 1 and 2 of Block 1, in the City of Santa Clarita, County of Los Angeles, State of California, as per Map recorded in Book 1, Page 1 of Miscellaneous Maps, in the Office of the County Recorder of said County "
        , "sentences": 
        [{
            "tokens": 
            [
                        {"id": 1, "orth": "Lots", "ner": "B-LOT"}
                        , {"id": 2, "orth": "1", "ner": "I-LOT"}
                        , {"id": 3, "orth": "and", "ner": "I-LOT"}
                        , {"id": 4, "orth": "2", "ner": "L-LOT"}
                        , {"id": 5, "orth": "of", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 6, "orth": "Block", "ner": "B-BLOCK"}
                        , {"id": 7, "orth": "1,", "ner": "L-BLOCK"}
                        , {"id": 8, "orth": "in", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 9, "orth": "the", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 10, "orth": "City", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 11, "orth": "of", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 12, "orth": "Santa", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 13, "orth": "Clarita,", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 14, "orth": "County", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 15, "orth": "of", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 16, "orth": "Los", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 17, "orth": "Angeles,", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 18, "orth": "State", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 19, "orth": "of", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 20, "orth": "California,", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 21, "orth": "as", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 22, "orth": "per", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 23, "orth": "Map", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 24, "orth": "recorded", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 25, "orth": "in", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 26, "orth": "Book", "ner": "B-BOOK"}
                        , {"id": 27, "orth": "1,", "ner": "L-BOOK"}
                        , {"id": 28, "orth": "Page", "ner": "B-PAGE"}
                        , {"id": 29, "orth": "1", "ner": "L-PAGE"}
                        , {"id": 30, "orth": "of", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 31, "orth": "Miscellaneous", "ner": "B-MAPTYPE"}
                        , {"id": 32, "orth": "Maps,", "ner": "L-MAPTYPE"}
                        , {"id": 33, "orth": "in", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 34, "orth": "the", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 35, "orth": "Office", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 36, "orth": "of", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 37, "orth": "the", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 38, "orth": "County", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 39, "orth": "Recorder", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 40, "orth": "of", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 41, "orth": "said", "ner": "O"}
                        , {"id": 42, "orth": "County", "ner": "O"}
            ]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I took the Train.py file that comes with spaCy in the cli folder and created my own version for this process. I left the core functionality of the file in tact and just added a few things such as some new labels for my data set and a custom tokenizer that works with white space instead of the conventional tokenizer. The function is below:

```
def NERTrain(lang
          , output_dir
          , train_data
          , dev_data
          , n_iter=30
          , n_sents=0
          , parser_multitasks=''
          , entity_multitasks=''
          , use_gpu=-1
          , vectors=None
          , gold_preproc=False
          , version="0.0.0"
          , meta_path=None
          , verbose=False
          , newLabels = None):
    """
    Train a model. Expects data in spaCy's JSON format.
    """
    util.fix_random_seed()
    util.set_env_log(True)
    n_sents = n_sents or None
    output_path = util.ensure_path(output_dir)
    train_path = util.ensure_path(train_data)
    dev_path = util.ensure_path(dev_data)
    meta_path = util.ensure_path(meta_path)
    if not output_path.exists():
        output_path.mkdir()
    if not train_path.exists():
        prints(train_path, title=Messages.M050, exits=1)
    if dev_path and not dev_path.exists():
        prints(dev_path, title=Messages.M051, exits=1)
    if meta_path is not None and not meta_path.exists():
        prints(meta_path, title=Messages.M020, exits=1)
    meta = util.read_json(meta_path) if meta_path else {}
    if not isinstance(meta, dict):
        prints(Messages.M053.format(meta_type=type(meta)),
               title=Messages.M052, exits=1)
    meta.setdefault('lang', lang)
    meta.setdefault('name', 'unnamed')

    pipeline = ['ner']

    # Take dropout and batch size as generators of values -- dropout
    # starts high and decays sharply, to force the optimizer to explore.
    # Batch size starts at 1 and grows, so that we make updates quickly
    # at the beginning of training.
    dropout_rates = util.decaying(util.env_opt('dropout_from', 0.2),
                                  util.env_opt('dropout_to', 0.2),
                                  util.env_opt('dropout_decay', 0.0))
    batch_sizes = util.compounding(util.env_opt('batch_from', 1),
                                   util.env_opt('batch_to', 16),
                                   util.env_opt('batch_compound', 1.001))
    max_doc_len = util.env_opt('max_doc_len', 5000)
    corpus = GoldCorpus(train_path, dev_path, limit=n_sents)
    n_train_words = corpus.count_train()

    lang_class = util.get_lang_class(lang)
    nlp = lang_class()

    if "ner" in nlp.pipe_names:
        nlp.remove_pipe("ner")

    ner = nlp.create_pipe("ner")
    nlp.add_pipe(ner, first=True)

    meta['pipeline'] = pipeline
    nlp.meta.update(meta)
    if vectors:
        print("Load vectors model", vectors)
        util.load_model(vectors, vocab=nlp.vocab)
        for lex in nlp.vocab:
            values = {}
            for attr, func in nlp.vocab.lex_attr_getters.items():
                # These attrs are expected to be set by data. Others should
                # be set by calling the language functions.
                if attr not in (CLUSTER, PROB, IS_OOV, LANG):
                    values[lex.vocab.strings[attr]] = func(lex.orth_)
            lex.set_attrs(**values)
            lex.is_oov = False
#    for name in pipeline:
#        nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe(name), name=name)
    if parser_multitasks:
        for objective in parser_multitasks.split(','):
            nlp.parser.add_multitask_objective(objective)
    if entity_multitasks:
        for objective in entity_multitasks.split(','):
            nlp.entity.add_multitask_objective(objective)
    optimizer = nlp.begin_training(lambda: corpus.train_tuples, device=use_gpu)
    nlp._optimizer = None
    nlp.tockenizer=WTok(nlp)
    other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != "ner"]

    if(newLabels != None):
        for l in newLabels:
            ner.add_label(l)

    print("Itn.  Dep Loss  NER Loss  UAS     NER P.  NER R.  NER F.  Tag %   Token %  CPU WPS  GPU WPS")
    try:
        train_docs = corpus.train_docs(nlp, projectivize=True, noise_level=0.0,
                                       gold_preproc=gold_preproc, max_length=0)
        train_docs = list(train_docs)
        with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):
            for i in range(n_iter):
                with tqdm.tqdm(total=n_train_words, leave=False) as pbar:
                    losses = {}
                    for batch in minibatch(train_docs, size=batch_sizes):
                        batch = [(d, g) for (d, g) in batch if len(d) < max_doc_len]
                        if not batch:
                            continue
                        docs, golds = zip(*batch)
                        nlp.update(docs, golds, sgd=optimizer,
                                   drop=next(dropout_rates), losses=losses)
                        pbar.update(sum(len(doc) for doc in docs))

                with nlp.use_params(optimizer.averages):
                    util.set_env_log(False)
                    epoch_model_path = output_path / ('model%d' % i)
                    nlp.to_disk(epoch_model_path)
                    nlp_loaded = util.load_model_from_path(epoch_model_path)
                    dev_docs = list(corpus.dev_docs(
                                    nlp_loaded,
                                    gold_preproc=gold_preproc))
                    nwords = sum(len(doc_gold[0]) for doc_gold in dev_docs)
                    start_time = timer()
                    scorer = nlp_loaded.evaluate(dev_docs, verbose)
                    end_time = timer()
                    if use_gpu < 0:
                        gpu_wps = None
                        cpu_wps = nwords/(end_time-start_time)
                    else:
                        gpu_wps = nwords/(end_time-start_time)
                        with Model.use_device('cpu'):
                            nlp_loaded = util.load_model_from_path(epoch_model_path)
                            dev_docs = list(corpus.dev_docs(
                                            nlp_loaded, gold_preproc=gold_preproc))
                            start_time = timer()
                            scorer = nlp_loaded.evaluate(dev_docs)
                            end_time = timer()
                            cpu_wps = nwords/(end_time-start_time)
                    acc_loc = (output_path / ('model%d' % i) / 'accuracy.json')
                    with acc_loc.open('w') as file_:
                        file_.write(json_dumps(scorer.scores))
                    meta_loc = output_path / ('model%d' % i) / 'meta.json'
                    meta['accuracy'] = scorer.scores
                    meta['speed'] = {'nwords': nwords, 'cpu': cpu_wps,
                                     'gpu': gpu_wps}
                    meta['vectors'] = {'width': nlp.vocab.vectors_length,
                                       'vectors': len(nlp.vocab.vectors),
                                       'keys': nlp.vocab.vectors.n_keys}
                    meta['lang'] = nlp.lang
                    meta['pipeline'] = pipeline
                    meta['spacy_version'] = '>=%s' % about.__version__
                    meta.setdefault('name', 'model%d' % i)
                    meta.setdefault('version', version)

                    with meta_loc.open('w') as file_:
                        file_.write(json_dumps(meta))
                    util.set_env_log(True)
                print_progress(i, losses, scorer.scores, cpu_wps=cpu_wps,
                               gpu_wps=gpu_wps)
    finally:
        print("Saving model...")
        with nlp.use_params(optimizer.averages):
            final_model_path = output_path / 'model-final'
            nlp.to_disk(final_model_path)
```

**What I've Done**

When the attempting to run the full JSON file failed, I attempted the same with a smaller sample of 100. The process was able to run all the way through with no issues. Now before I go chopping up my dataset into bite sized chunks of 100 (which i really don't want / shouldn't have to do) i wanted to see if anyone could take a look and see if this is possibly some sort of 1. limit in spacy i have somehow hit, 2. memory issue, 3. or some sort of code issue i overlooked.

Please be advised that this process is being run on my local machine which is speced as follows:

**PC specs**

Windows 10
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6600U CPU @ 2.6GHz 2.81 GHz
16.0 GB Ram
Python 3.7.4
spaCy 2.0.16

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you

**EDIT 1:**

After i asked this question, i figured in the mean time i would attempt to process my files in small batches of 100. Interestingly enough, one of the files caused the process to crash. Immediately i thought it was a data issue, so i added a "print" to the training function so i can see which text was causing it. But after i added the "print" the file completed without error. I am not sure what to make of this but just some added information.

**EDIT 2:**

I was finally able to get an error message related to the crash. 
*Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF8EB9E2BE2 (ner.cp37-win_amd64.pyd) in python.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000001C4213D1FE4. occurred*
The error is marked on invoke_main() within exe_common.inl
I've attempted to find more information about this error and only found very little. It appears to be some kind of Windows error? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there an error message when it crashes?

Comment: no sir, when running from a IDE it simply just stops. When i run from the command line it says "Python has stopped working" and gives me an option to debug or close. When i choose debug nothing loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end this turned out to be version incompatibilities between some of spaCy's dependents. This appears to have been caused by several uninstalls and re-installs of older and newer versions of spaCy. I got a fresh environment made and installed only the most current version of spaCy and everything works great. If you are using Anaconda Navigator i would not trust the package installer from the UI. It appears to be linked to older versions and you are much better off using PIP from the terminal.